# FTP inbound channel adapter stops working after connection reset

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration

We're currently polling an FTP folder for XLSX files with Spring Integration 3.0.2.
When the data connection is reset, the poller stops working however. All the files on the FTP server remain on the FTP, so no polling is executed.

I've read that prior to v 3.0 of SI, the connections were cached, and caused some issues, but normally this should not be the case, since we use a normal FtpSessionFactory.

Stacktrace:

```
2015-01-06 16:26:15,444 ERROR [] () [de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.dataimport.batch.task.ErrorHandler] unexpected exception caught
org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:189)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.receive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:162)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:184)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:143)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:141)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:273)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:268)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:306)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:163)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create FTPClient
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.AbstractFtpSessionFactory.getSession(AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:295)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:175)
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.CRLFLineReader.readLine(CRLFLineReader.java:58)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:310)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:290)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP._connectAction_(FTP.java:392)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._connectAction_(FTPClient.java:764)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:169)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:189)
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.AbstractFtpSessionFactory.createClient(AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:152)
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.AbstractFtpSessionFactory.getSession(AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:136)
    ... 22 more
```

Configuration:

```
<int:channel id="ftpChannel">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>

<bean id="ftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="abcd.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="21"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
    <property name="fileType" value="2"/>
    <property name="clientMode" value="2" />
</bean>

<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="supplierImportFtpChannel"
                                 channel="ftpChannel"
                                 session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
                                 local-directory="/localdirectory"
                                 remote-directory="/ftpdirectory"
                                 filename-regex=".*\.xlsx$"
                                 delete-remote-files="true"
                                 temporary-file-suffix=".writing">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the framework that would "stop" the poller after such an exception.

Most likely the poller thread is hung on the next poll trying to connect to the server - you can verify that with a thread dump (using jstack).

There is no timeout (by default) when connecting.

Starting with 4.0, you can now [configure timeouts](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1131/files) directly on the `DefaultFtpSessionFactory`; prior to 4.0 you have to use the technique [described in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-session-factory) (scroll down to **Advanced Configuration**).

Comment: Thank you Gary, I'll try your solution for 3.0 and will provide feedback!